# Randomly Task Allocation to Employee with percentage in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I’m working on the macro which will allocate task randomly to the employee as per assigned percentage. I wasn’t able to prepare/get exact vba code for it. Requesting help on this.
E.g. I’ve a sheet with multiple columns (A - Task, B - Sample 1, C - Assigned) & rows (contains tasks i.e. Task 1  to Task 8). Also I’ve employee list with percentage of allocation. 
Sachin - 50%
Rahul - 30%
Ajay - 20%

What final output i want that apply filter “A” in column (Sample 1) & assign task randomly to employee with their percentage on visible cells.

I was able to get it via loop method; however I'm looking it by randomization method. I mean randomly allocate with their respective percentages. Thanks!
Please see below code -

```
Dim Total as Integer
Dim Sachin as Integer
Dim Rahul as Integer
Dim Ajay as Integer
Dim i, j as Integer
      With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion    
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Critria1:="A"
      End With
      ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C" & Cells(Row.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

Set RowRange = Selection
    Total = 0
For Each rw In RowRange.Rows
    Total = Total + 1
Next rw

Sachin = Total * 0.5
Rahul = Total * 0.25
Ajay = Total * 0.25

i = 0
For Each rw In RowRange.Rows
j = i mod 3
    If Sachin >=1 And j = 0 Then
       Cells(rw.Row, 10) = "Sachin"
       Sachin = Sachin - 1
    ElseIf Rahul = 0 And Ajay = 0 Then
       Cells(rw.Row, 10) = "Sachin"
       Sachin = Sachin - 1
    End If

    If Rahul >=1 And j = 1 Then
       Cells(rw.Row, 10) = "Rahul"
       Rahul = Rahul - 1
    End If

    If Ajay >=1 And j = 2 Then
      Cells(rw.Row, 10) = "Ajay"
      Ajay = Ajay - 1
    End If

i = i + 1
Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: *"Actually I’m working on the macro …"* If you are working on it that means you have tried something. Please show what you have tried so we can point you in the right direction what you need to change/fix. Also include which errors you got and where, where you got stuck or what your code actually does versus what you expected it to do. Please also see what a [mcve] is and provide proper input/output example data (screenshots might help as well).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've put code here. Actually I was able to get result via loop method. But I'm looking for randomization method (randomly allocation to visible cells after filter).